# export the listview items to excel sheet with listview header

Tags: vb.net

I have this code to export the data in listview to excel sheet, but this code export data without the header of list view.

How can I edit this code to show the header of the listview?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Excel File"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xslx"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    'exit if no file selected
    If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'create objects to interface to Excel
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    'create a workbook and get reference to first worksheet
    xls.Workbooks.Add()
    book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = book.ActiveSheet
    'step through rows and columns and copy data to worksheet
    Dim row As Integer = 1
    Dim col As Integer = 1
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
            sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
            col = col + 1
        Next
        row += 1
        col = 1
    Next
    'save the workbook and clean up
    book.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()
    releaseObject(sheet)
    releaseObject(book)
    releaseObject(xls)
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    'Release an automation object
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each column text by using this code:

```
Dim columns As New List(Of String)
    Dim columncount As Integer = ListView1.Columns.Count - 1


    For i As Integer = 0 To columncount
        columns.Add(ListView1.Columns(i).Text)
    Next


    For Each columnname In columns
        MessageBox.Show(columnname)
    Next
```

Comment: how can i add your code in my code ?? please give me the full code if you can @someNickName

Comment: Well, with my code on the second For each, you got the names of the header of each column  ordered by left-to-right, you can't adapt it ? :p
I never exported to excell or used excell with vb, but, if you can add it to one row above the items your adding and continuing to the right it'd suit your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you enter the loop to export your data you need to iterate the [ColumnHeaderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnheadercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the `ListView`

```
For i = 0 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
  sheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = ListView1.Items(i).Name
Next
```

Comment: hello , when i add the code you talk about it , i have error .... can you modify my code please @jeff

Answer (score 1):

```
 SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Excel File"
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        'exit if no file selected
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'create objects to interface to Excel
        Dim xls As New Excel.Application
        Dim book As Excel.Workbook
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'create a workbook and get reference to first worksheet
        xls.Workbooks.Add()
        book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
        sheet = book.ActiveSheet

        'step through rows and columns and copy data to worksheet
        Dim row As Integer = 2
        Dim col As Integer = 1

        '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Dim rowhead As Integer = 1
        Dim colhead As Integer = 1

        Dim columns As New List(Of String)
        Dim columncount As Integer = LvCOCONFIRMATION.Columns.Count - 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To columncount
            sheet.Cells(rowhead, colhead) = LvCOCONFIRMATION.Columns(i).Text
            colhead = colhead + 1
        Next
        '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        For Each item As ListViewItem In LvCOCONFIRMATION.Items
            For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
                sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
                col = col + 1
            Next
            row += 1
            col = 1
        Next

        'save the workbook and clean up
        book.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        xls.Workbooks.Close()
        xls.Quit()
        releaseObject(sheet)
        releaseObject(book)
        releaseObject(xls)
```